# Copy & Paste selected text

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new in IntelliJ IDEA and I want to copy & paste the Selection on the IDE, but Copy & Paste does not work

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy the tool-tip message press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while right clicking anywhere on the tooltip.

For MacOS <kbd>⌥</kbd> while right clicking anywhere on the tooltip.

Then you can open the latest IntelliJ latest copied items and copy the partial string you wanted (e.g class name) from there.

To open the latest copied items:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
or on MacOS: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>